# Spring MVC having trouble getting JSP to display Controller Value

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC I have setup a test DB to try to get a single flow through and  have a table displayed in a JSP page.  I assume I have something configured wrong but I cannot find it.  Maybe a naming convention.

I have a mySql DB
A DAO Class that just does a select * from my table that works as I can step into it.

My controller just gets a list of my Run Models.  No errors are thrown The JSP simple loads an empty table.  The controller seems to have the correct info in it.

Model (snippet all the getters and setters seem to work as the controller gets a list of them fine)

```
public class QAModel {

private int idRun;
private String SuiteID;
private String run_name;
```

Controller Code

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/RunList")
public ModelAndView listRun(ModelAndView model) throws IOException{
    //@ModelAttribute
    System.out.println("**** Controller ******");

    List<QAModel> listRun = runDao.list();
    model.addObject("RunList", listRun);
    model.setViewName("RunList");

    return model;
}
```

That does get a list of Run Model Objects that contain the correct DB info I can see them if I step into it. However the JSP loads a blank table.

JSP Code (I assume I'm missing some mapping or naming convention?)

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Contact Manager Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div align="center">
            <h1>Contact List</h1>
            <h3><a href="/newRun">New Run</a></h3>
            <table border="1">
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Suite ID</th>
                <th>Run Name</th>


                <c:forEach var="QAModel" items="${RunList}" varStatus="status">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${status.index + 1}</td>
                        <td>${QAModel.SuiteID}</td>
                        <td>${QAModel.run_name}</td>

                    <td>
                        <a href="/editRun?id=${run.id}">Edit</a>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <a href="/deleteRun?id=${run.id}">Delete</a>
                    </td>

                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>

            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should be fine, but: Your JSP is missing a `<tr>` around the `<th>` tags. You have 3 `<th>` tags, but 4 `<td>` tags. 4th `<td>` tag uses `run` but loop var is `QAModel`. --- When you say "blank table", do you mean empty rows, or no rows?

Comment: The table looks fine in the browser it is just blank.  I see the headers and the links but nothing from my controller

Comment: Also I'm running this in eclipse if that makes a difference.

Comment: JSP EL uses bean syntax, meaning that your getter methods are probably misnamed. Names in the JSP should start with lowercase `suiteID`, and the getter method should be camelcase `getSuiteID()` and `getRun_time()`. Or rename to `.runTime` in JSP and `getRunTime()`.

Comment: I thought I had to match stuff to my column names in db.  So I have a column name  "run_name" so my model method is "private String run_name;"  and getter  ->    public String getRun_name() {return run_name;}

Comment: Maybe this is where I am off so when I inspect my "model" object in my controller which is what gets returned to the JSP.  I see the string names from my model which match my DB column names.  "idRun", "run_name", "SuiteID"   so I thought in my JSP I needed to ask for those like so "<td>${QAModel.run_name}</td>"  Is this correct or not.

Comment: Not knowing the implementation of `runDao.list()`, who can say? Is it an ORM, or plain JDBC? Either way, your model objects *fields* do **not** have to be named the same as the database *columns*, though some kind of relation would be good. --- *Example:* Table named `User` with a column named `UserName`, may map to a model object called `User` with a field called `name`, such that it has `getName()` and `setName()`. In JSP, you'd access it as `<c:out value="${user.name}"/>`. --- See how the shortened field name works out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not able to print any jstl variable then one possible reason can be that your jstl core tag is not added.

Add this to begining of your JSP file.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Comment: That tag lib did it!!  I also had my naming messed up which I cleaned up as stated above.  Thanks all!  Now that I have a simple working page I feel I can play around and learn more of the framework.